# BottomNavigationView Does not exists

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-support-design

I am trying to use navigationeditor with bottom navigation view, but it seems that bottomnavigationview is only causing the issue.

This is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wedding.rashmilind"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-alpha04'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0'
}
```

This is the error I am getting on runnig the code :

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.wedding.rashmilind-zTaNp816F4MRKuZ8FBDtjw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wedding.rashmilind-zTaNp816F4MRKuZ8FBDtjw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wedding.rashmilind-zTaNp816F4MRKuZ8FBDtjw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wedding.rashmilind-zTaNp816F4MRKuZ8FBDtjw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wedding.rashmilind-zTaNp816F4MRKuZ8FBDtjw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wedding.rashmilind-zTaNp816F4MRKuZ8FBDtjw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wedding.rashmilind-zTaNp816F4MRKuZ8FBDtjw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wedding.rashmilind-zTaNp816F4MRKuZ8FBDtjw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wedding.rashmilind-zTaNp816F4MRKuZ8FBDtjw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wedding.rashmilind-zTaNp816F4MRKuZ8FBDtjw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wedding.rashmilind-zTaNp816F4MRKuZ8FBDtjw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wedding.rashmilind-zTaNp816F4MRKuZ8FBDtjw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.wedding.rashmilind-zTaNp816F4MRKuZ8FBDtjw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.wedding.rashmilind-zTaNp816F4MRKuZ8FBDtjw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

It only gets this view : `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you have migrated to AndroidX...try using `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` instead

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Comment: Are all the features and methods same for both?

Comment: @ParthAnjaria yes, fully compatible. Just moved to a different package/library

Answer (score 0):

ON MAC CMD+SHIFT+R

Then replace all occurance of

> android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

With

> com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView